# C# Parsing Datarows

Tags: c#, datatable

Scenario:

Based on user interaction, one of several stored procedures will be called, each having different result structure, so I can't strongly type the return.

I am using Petapoco and returning `IEnumerable<dynamic>` rows, converting to a datatable (which takes about 245ms) then looping through the rows in the datatable's rows and appending to a string creating an html table.

One result is returning over 3000 lines and is taking almost 2 minutes to parse.

How can I improve this?  Each row is only taking around 35ms so individually not a problem.

I'd rather not have to add pagination if I can get away with it.

Comment: Why are you converting to a datatable?

Comment: @Eyvind:  I didn't have time to look into how to get the table headers.  I found some quick 'dump to datatable' code which I'm using.

Comment: @Eyvind: Could you explain how I would inteerrogate this data without converting it to a datatable? One of the queries is taking forever to dump to datatable so there must be something unusual going on with it.  If I can avoid doing it I save my user having to sit and watch a progressbar... Thanks.

Comment: @SamDelaney I'm not quite sure what you mean by "interrogate" the data, but couldn't you just loop through it directly, say something like 

foreach(dynamic row in rows) { Console.WriteLine(row.MyField); } ?

Comment: I just mean look at the data and do something with it.  If I knew what fields I'd be getting from the spreocs I'd be able to strict type the return. I don't, therefore putting it into a datatable means I just have to loop through the rows/columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely using a `StringBuilder` is the solution.

Instead of appending to a string instance:

```
var html = "";

foreach(var row in rows)
    html += "<p>" + row + "</p>";
```

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var row in rows)
    sb.Append("<p>" + row + "</p>");

var html = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Annoyingly, I never build my strings with string +=, but on this occasion I did.  Had I done it like I normally do with StringBuilder, my parsing would have been mere milliseconds.  Lesson learnt...  Thanks.